# World map paths data in react high charts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, highcharts, npm

I am looking at the react highmaps documentation and it seems like they have hardcoded/saved the map data.

[Link 1](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts)

[Link 2](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/tree/master/demo/src/mapdata)

I see in a lot of little tutorials though that the data comes from high maps itself by just passing a key like this

```
mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/tooltip/usehtml/)

But given that I am writing a pure reactJS/ nodeJS app, I was wondering if there is a way in pure react to pull in the path data for world maps? Is this deployed to react high maps somewhere?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Data for a map in highcharts react is just an object, ready to import if it necessary. So if you need it, import it as a regular module.

Comment: When I use npm to install highcharts the Highcharts.maps object is empty.

Comment: It's confirmed by HighSoft from June 6, 2018 that their map collection is not available on npm. For further reference read comments of the following the link: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/frameworks/react/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react/ The only solution of your case is given below by @Jordan Enev.

Comment: the maps are now available on npm. `npm i @highcharts/map-collection`

Answer (score 15):

According the [official Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection) you have to manualy include the map script:

> In short, the GeoJSON version of the map is loaded in a script tag in
>   the page. This GeoJSON object is then registered to the
>   Highcharts.maps object, and applied to the mapData option in the chart
>   setup.

As you can see in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/tooltip/usehtml/) you mentioned, they included the map with the script tag:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

Because of the above script include, the map is available in `Highcharts.maps['custom/world']`.

So in the React module you have to manually add the desired maps, like in the demo you mentioned. For example, if you want to add the World map, then:

1. Get it from here: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js
2. Replace `Highcharts.maps["custom/world"] =` with `module.exports =` in the above file.
3. Load the map in your component `const map = require('./maps/world');`
4. Then you can reference it in the config `mapData: map`

I understand that you want to skip the above process, but currently there isn't any React module that includes the map.

---

Actually there is a hackish way you can do it ... In your html file, where the react scripts are included, there you can include world.js script tag, but first you have to make sure that Highcharts.maps object array exist. In that fashion you'll use the maps externally.

However this is a **bad practice**, because of your React's components will be dependend on that map script.

**Good practice** is to manage your vendor modules via package manager and reference the modules in the components. In that way the components are self-descriptive

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I asking. Sad there's no way to do it!

Comment: @es3735746 actually there is a hackish way you can do it ... In your html file, where the react scripts are included, there you can include world.js script tag, but first you have to make sure that `Highcharts.maps` object array exist.

In that fashion you'll use the maps externally.

However **this is a bad practice**, because of your React's components will be dependend on that map script.

**Good practice** is to manage your vendor modules via package manager and reference the modules in the components. In that way - the components are self-descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

The maps are now available from npm. You can import them directly into your component and pass it to Highcharts through the options object.

`npm i @highcharts/map-collection`

`import mapDataWorld from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json'`

```
series: [
  {
    mapData: mapDataWorld,
    name: "Asia",
    data: data
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I find another ways to render the map.

```
series: [{
          data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/cou ... /us-all.js']),
          name: 'USA',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.properties.postal-code}'
          }
}]
```

[From highcharts forum example](https://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?t=39799)

Basically call the js source url to create the map, but I prefer use Jordan Enev's way.

After I take a look, highcharts already gave the map collection, you can install the dependency @highcharts/map-collection [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@highcharts/map-collection)

After that you can try

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
import exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
...
...
exporting(Highcharts);
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
require('@highcharts/map-collection/countries/id/id-all');
...
...
class Choroplethmap extends Component {
...
...
...
}
export default Choroplethmap;
```

This issue already raise on this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4994)

Cheers,