# Highmaps in Typescript: Maps not being dipslayed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to use a highmap of the highcharts package in typescript using react. However, it does not display the map at all.

See a live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/o9nokjr6vz

It is related to this option:

```
Highcharts.mapChart("investment", {
  chart: {
    map: "countries/de/de-all"
  },
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have not given the chart any mapData, you need to include http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/de/de-all.js.

Comment: ...possibly this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844962/world-map-paths-data-in-react-high-charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapdata for your referenced 'countries/de/de-all' was not loaded for your map. You have to download the GeoJson file for Germany [here](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/de/de-all.geo.json) and upload the json file to your project and import it like this;

```
import * as mapdata from "./de-all.geo.json";
```

and set the map data as follows

```
Highcharts.mapChart("investment", {
      chart: {
        //map: "countries/de/de-all"
        map: mapdata
      },
```

See forked demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j210020nwv):

Of course would this have been made easier when the Highcharts maps were made available through npm.