# Highcharts Map with React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to write [the WorldMap example](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/all-maps) with TypeScript and I have issues with the series inside Highcharts Options:

```
(Highcharts, Highstock, Highmaps, Gantt) Series options for specific data and the data itself. In TypeScript you have to cast the series options to specific series types, to get all possible options for a series.
```

It looks like the `series` requires `type: 'map'` but I've tried that and it didn't work.
I've also looked at samples and answers online ([1](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection),[2](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#highcharts-with-typescript), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844962/world-map-paths-data-in-react-high-charts), [4](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=39804)), but they only work for React in `jsx` not `tsx`.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

import mapDataWorld from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    series: [
        {
          mapData: mapDataWorld,
        //   data: data,
          name: "USA",
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: "{point.name}"
          }
        }
    ],
}

export default function HighchartsTest(props: HighchartsReact.Props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <HighchartsReact
                highcharts={Highcharts}
                options={options}
                {...props}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some issues in your attempt.

1. The map module is not imported (highmaps in this case).
2. Missing constructorType in

   ```
   constructorType={'mapChart'}
   ```

And here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zs69rw?file=index.tsx

Notice that type must be defined and also data array needs to has defined types. I think that the issue has occurred in your case because of missing modules.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I was looking for that example. I did find it somewhere but I couldn't find it again. I actually did try what you suggested as I mentioned here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/196 but it still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Let me know whether everything works as you expected.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. The example you showed me helps a lot!